# What is the gravity/inertia question?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, projectile, inertia

Is the discussion about how gravity and inertia are the same, about the idea that when you hit a ball, it doesn't come back but when you throw a ball up, it does come back?

Comment: Welcome to this community! Rather, it's connected to the idea that if you let go of two balls (in a vacuum), you'll see that they have the same acceleration, no matter the difference in their material and constitution. (This isn't the whole story.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This discussion has nothing to do with a ball being hit or thrown.
It is about why the inertial mass is equal to the gravitational mass
(see also [inertial vs. gravitational mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass#Inertial_vs._gravitational_mass)).
But for explaining this I need to reach out more.

Inertial mass is how much a body refuses to be accelerated.
To accelerate a body with acceleration $\mathbf{a}$
you need to apply a force
$$\mathbf{F}_a=m_i \mathbf{a}.$$
The factor $m_i$ appearing here is called the [inertial mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass#Inertial_mass) of the body.

On the other hand, gravitational mass is how much a body reacts to gravity.
When a body is in a gravitational field of strength $\mathbf{g}$
then it is subject to the gravitational force
$$\mathbf{F}_g=m_g\mathbf{g}.$$
The factor $m_g$ appearing here is called the [gravitational mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass#Universal_gravitational_mass) of the body (or more precisely: the passive gravitational mass)).

Now it is known (already by Newton in 1680,
extending on Galilei's concepts from 1600) that for all bodies
these two masses ($m_i$ and $m_g$) are equal.
And therefore we usually call it just the mass of the body.
But why are these two equal? This is a simple but highly non-trivial question.
And even Newton didn't have an answer for this.

It took until 1915 (Einstein's theory of [general relativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_relativity))
to get an explanation for this coincidence.
Actually this theory begins with the [equivalence
principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_principle#The_weak_equivalence_principle), claiming that a gravitational field
and and an acceleration are not distinguishable from each other.
Or saying in other words: The gravitational force is also kind of
an [inertial force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fictitious_force), and therefore proportional to the inertial mass.

Comment: A mention of Galileo might be nice for laypersons, since his concept was used by Newton.

Comment: @N.Steinle ok, good idea